# Writing a story online

Tags: creative-writing, publishing

I've been wondering, is there any outlets available that allow you to publish a book online in a similar format as Webcomics? A sort of, 'Webnovel'?

Is there any appropriate name for this, where you release a chapter every week or so?

---

Edit: I've found a term that may be relevant: Serial Novel.

Answer (score 6):

## It is called a blog.

Many authors have serialized novels in their blogs, sometimes between other posts, sometimes on a blog dedicated to the novel alone.

Before blog software existed, authors used to create a page on their website and add new chapters at the end. This is no longer common.

When you set up a blog, you have two options to sort the chapters or updates: from newest to oldest (so that visitors see what is new) or from oldest to newest (so that visitors can easily find the beginning), and some blog software allows the visitor to choose the sorting.

---

If you don't want to manage your own blog, there are also literary online magazines that publish many authors. The software behind this is usually also a blog software such as Wordpress. What magazines there are in your genre, language, and country, I do not know.

Comment: "sometimes between other posts" - bonus points for tagging all blogposts that form a part of the story in such a way thatvreaders can easily get the entire serialized novelvand nothing else, if they wish.

Answer (score 2):

Wattpad works. It's a website that will allow you to publish online and read other users' books, too. That's what I use. I haven't actually heard of any other website like that...Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

There's [FanFiction](http://www.fanfiction.net/) or [FimFiction](http://www.fimfiction.net/) (if it's set in someone else's work) or [FictionPress](http://www.fictionpress.com) if it's an original piece. [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/) and a personal blog have been mentioned, but there are also the collection of [NaNoWriMo](http://nanowrimo.org/) (National November Writer's Month) sites out there, and plenty of other sites available.

I, personally, use FanFiction to sharpen my writing skills and have people read my work. It's a very active site, and there are plenty of writers there willing to offer feedback. There is also a 'beta finder' of sorts, but I personally wouldn't use it (most never update their information, or simply never get back to you).

I've had quite a few writers trying to entice me to join them in the NaNoWriMo competitions, and as I understand it there are some groups that are super active and supportive within that circle. I have no personal experience there, so I will not act as if I do.

There's also Google Docs, where you can place the story online and share a link with whomever you want. I'm sure there are other more private options as well, but none I can think of off the top of my head.

If that isn't what you're looking for, you might want to google around, see what other options there are. This is the internet, there's always another way.

Comment: Does FanFiction support custom works? I thought its more of, well... you know - 'fanfiction'.

Comment: No. FanFiction does not, they have FictionPress for that--same support staff, different 'site'.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/) for posting samples and excerpts, but it is a dedicated writing sharing platform, which allows you post full-length works as well with no limits, and it is modern-looking, feature-rich, and free.

If you want more control over your work (who sees it, can comment on it, etc.) you might want to explore a blog option per @what's suggestion. There are [free options](https://wordpress.com/) as well.